# Global Ban excepts certain servers Discord.JS

Tags: discord.js

so I found a code to ban a member from every server the bot is in, also known as, global ban. I like this feature, however, I want it to ignore a certain server. For example, I have a Complaint or Ban Appeal Discord, and when I ban a member, it will also ban the member from the Complaint/Ban Appeals server. Now, I don't want that. I want it to ban from all of the bot's servers, but not that exact server. Is there are a way I can ignore a certain server from banning a member?

```
client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => a.members.ban(member.id))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can ignore a certain server doing something like this:

```js
client.guilds.cache.forEach(a => {
    if(a.id != 'YOUR_SUPPORT_SERVER_ID') {
        a.members.ban(member.id)
    }
})
```

Sobstitute the string with the guild id of the server you want to ignore.